# Django Haystack: filter query based on multiple items in a list.

Tags: django, search, django-haystack, relation, django-queryset

I have Event model instances that can belong to one or more Organization model instances.  I've implemented haystack 2.0.0 to index all of my Events.  Here is an example search index.

```
class EventIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):

    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    organization_slug = indexes.CharField(model_attr='organization__slug',
                        weight=5.0)
    organization_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='organization__name', 
                        weight=5.0)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name', weight=10.0)

    ....    

    def get_model(self):
        return Event

    def index_queryset(self):
        return Event.objects.filter()
```

**My question is how do I construct a SearchQuerySet query that filters Events based on one or several Organizations.**  For example, I want find all Events that belong to "orgnization1" and "organization3" (where the list of organizations can be any length long)

As a Django query it might look something like this:

```
Event.objects.filter(organization__in=[orgnization1, organization3]).filter(...)
```

How do I translate this to a haystack query? This is my attempt, but I don't really know what I'm doing...

```
organization_list = [organization1.slug, organization2.slug]
SearchQuerySet().filter_or(organization__contains=organization_list)
```

Here is an example of how my models look:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64) 
    organization = models.ForeignKey('mymodule.Organization')
    ...

class Organization(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=64)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ...
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think I've found a solution.  Just sharing it.  Apparently, Haystack has an object called a SQ(), which functions similar to Django's Q() object.  I found somewhere that you can invoke the add() method on Django's Q object instances to add more query parameters.  Seems to work the same way with SQ.

```
from haystack.forms import SearchForm
from haystack.query import SQ, SearchQuerySet
from haystack.views import SearchView

class CustomSerchView(SearchView):


    def __call__(self, request):

        self.request = request

        ########### Custom stuff
        user = request.user
        organization_list = [organization1.slug, organization2.slug, ....]

        sq = SQ()
        for slug in organization_list:
            sq.add(SQ(organization_slug=slug), SQ.OR)
        sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(sq)        
        ##########

        self.form = self.build_form(form_kwargs={'searchqueryset':sqs})
        self.query = self.get_query()
        self.results = self.get_results()
        return self.create_response()
```

Comment: I realize this is quite old, but you can .filter(organization_slug__in=organization_list)